# mongodb При присоединении коллекции выводить как отдельную запись

Tags: mongodb

Есть две коллекции:

```
    users:

    [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "user1"
            active: "true"
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            name: "user2",
            active: true
        }
    ]
    orders:

    [

        {
            id: 1,
            status: "payment",
            user_id: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            status: null,
            user_id: 1
        }

    ]
```

При присоединении "orders" с использованием $aggregate $lookup, результат выглядит так:

```
    [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "user1",
    orders: [
      {
        id: 1,
        status: "payment",
        user_id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        status: null,
        user_id: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "user2",
    active: true,
    orders: []
  }
]
```

То есть документы orders присоединяется к документу user в виде массива

Как сделать присоединение в виде объекта и вывод user как отдельной записи ?

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "user1",
    order: 
      {
        id: 1,
        status: "payment",
        user_id: 1
      },
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "user1",
    order: 
      {
        id: 2,
        status: null,
        user_id: 1
      }
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "user2",
    active: true,
    order: null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решилось всё так:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $lookup: {from: "orders", localField: "_id", foreignField: "user_id", as: "order"} },
  { $unwind: {
    "path": "$order",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  } }
])
```